# clearml hyperparameter optimization task fails on creating python environment

Tags: clearml

Trying to use clearml HyperparametersOptimizers. Launching task, but each experiment fails while trying to create python environment. Specificaly the error I get is related to pytorch

```
clearml_agent: Warning: could not resolve python wheel replacement for torch==1.1.0
Exception when trying to resolve python wheel: Could not find pytorch wheel URL for: torch==1.1.0 with cuda 113 support
clearml_agent: ERROR: Could not install task requirements!
Exception when trying to resolve python wheel: Could not find pytorch wheel URL for: torch==1.1.0 with cuda 113 support
```

I personally don't need pytorch for the code I am running and I removed it from the environment I am using, but the pytorch channel is present somewhere as it still tries to download it:

```
Executing Conda: "C:\Users\nir.s\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe" install -p "C:\Users\nir.s\.clearml\venvs-builds\3.7" -c defaults -c conda-forge -c pytorch "pip<20.2" --quiet --json
```

I am not sure if there is some configuration file that I missed or if it's because there are other parts of the repository that use pytorch, either way, as things are now I can't run tasks with clearml-agent since it fails to build an interpreter. Just to clarify, I do have environments working with pytorch for separate projects that use it. So the problem is not with anaconda or pip as it is installed on my computer since I can make it work when running locally.